# High MySQL Usage on WordPress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I noticed MySQL has a tendency to fluctuate from 9% CPU to 192% CPU in a heartbeat.

I found the database responsible, temporarily disabled it (to verify it was indeed responsible) and MySQL remained at a steady 9%.

The database in question is WordPress, and I recorded the following from MySQL's slow query log:

```
# Time: 220919 12:33:22
# User@Host: mysite_wp153[mysite_wp153] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 873  Schema: mysite_wp153  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 2.172042  Lock_time: 0.000194  Rows_sent: 6  Rows_examined: 1248320
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 155
SET timestamp=1663587202;
SELECT   wpak_posts.ID
                                        FROM wpak_posts  LEFT JOIN wpak_term_relationships ON (wpak_posts.ID = wpak_term_relationships.object_id)
                                        WHERE 1=1  AND (
  wpak_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (18,19,20,21)
) AND ((wpak_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wpak_posts.post_status = 'publish')))
                                        GROUP BY wpak_posts.ID
                                        ORDER BY wpak_posts.post_date DESC
                                        LIMIT 0, 6;
```

- I tried disabling all WordPress plugins, and the issue continued - so it does not appear to be plugin related.
- I tried setting up table indexes using the "Index WP MySQL For Speed" plugin - but that made no noticable difference.

Any thoughts/feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: slow query can be of many causes.. large number of rows, unindexed columns, processes being interrupted by anti virus, inadequate ram, failling disk, etc. you should [start digging around](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130082) the slow query log is a good start but the query wasn't always the reason.

Comment: If you have control over that query code then you can use query cache using `wp_cache_set` & `wp_cache_get`

Comment: @user12207241  Has your CPU busy become more stable?

Answer (score 1):

- Install [*WP Index Improvements Plugin*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)
- Speed up the group-order-by. By making them the same, thereby avoiding an extra sort:

  ```
    GROUP BY  wpak_posts.post_date DESC, wpak_posts.ID DESC
    ORDER BY  wpak_posts.post_date DESC, wpak_posts.ID DESC
  ```
- For further discussion, provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the particular query.